# Do I use a comma or a semicolon after a comma-separated list?

Tags: commas, semicolons

In the following sentence, should the last comma be changed to a semicolon because of the comma-separated list?

Whether your favorite toping is cheese, pepperoni, or sausage, this pizza party is for you.

Comment: You still use a comma, not a semicolon.

Comment: Whether your favorite topping is cheese, pepperoni, or sausage - this pizza party is for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comma is sufficient. It separates the main clause ('this pizza party is for you') from an adverbial clause describing the circumstances ('whether your favorite topping is cheese, pepperoni or sausage'). You could miss out the comma after 'pepperoni'.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would pick a colon or dash. A semicolon is more like an aside, some additional information.

A colon implies cause and effect, take note or everything before applies to the after.

A dash is similar to a semicolon, but it can also be used as a general pause and emphasis where the relation between the before and after its contextual.

I would make the final decision when I see it printed in the correct typeface and with the surrounding text to see what works better.